# SoundManager2 how to add sounds to play list

Tags: javascript, html, audio, soundmanager2

I am trying to code a HTML5 game. I am using Django as the main engine and SoundManager2 to deal with sound files.

I have 5 buttons with 5 different sounds and a Play button.

What I am trying to do is: when the user press a button the corresponding sound will be added to a list. Por example: user choose sound1 and sound3 to be played simultaneously.

My code right now is something like this:

```
soundManager.setup({
    preferFlash: false,
    //, url: "swf/"
    onready: function () {
```

**Next, the sound object to sound1**

```
soundManager.createSound({
            url: [
                "http://rpg.hamsterrepublic.com/wiki-images/6/67/ExtralongWarp.ogg"
            ],
            id: "1"
        });
```

**The sound object to sound2**

```
soundManager.createSound({
            url: [
                "http://rpg.hamsterrepublic.com/wiki-images/a/a2/ThunderMagic.ogg"
            ],
            id: "2"
        });
```

**prepare to play the sounds:**

```
    }
}).beginDelayedInit();

$("#play").click(function () {
    soundManager.stopAll();
```

**Sounds to be played at the same time:**

```
    soundManager.play("1");
    soundManager.play("2"); 

});
```

**My question is:** how can I add sound1 and sound2 objects, when the buttons are pressed, to a list and then play them?

Hard coded works well, as shown in the following example. But I need to use the buttons.

My code example: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/colepopiku/3/edit?html,js,output)

I am stuck in the middle of nowhere! :/

Comment: Instead of buttons, html checkboxes can be used!

Comment: Is possible to do this?